# Prolog, find element with a certain index

Tags: prolog

I know there are other solutions on the internet, but why isn't mine working?

```
find_thing(1,[H | _T], H). 
find_thing(2, [_H, M | _T], M).
find_thing(X,[_H | T], L) :- X1 is X - 1, find_thing(X1, T, L).
```

find_thing(2, [1,2,3], X) works and my compiler says that, when I use find_thing(3, [1,2,3], X), it crashes when it calls something like find_thing(2, [1,2,3] _2840).

Let it be known

```
find_thing(1,[H | _T], H) :- !. 
find_thing(2, [_H, M | _T], M) :- !.
find_thing(X,[_H | T], S) :- X >= 3, X1 is (X - 1), at_positon(X1, T, S).
```

is giving similar results

Comment: What do you mean it crashes, I run it the right solution (twice) but didn't crash.

Comment: o: really? I'm gonna try the online compiler and see if it is my compiler's fault.

Comment: another compiler says the same thing when I try to do find index 3's element

Comment: You mean in trace mode?? because querying find_thing(3, [1,2,3], X). gives right answers.

Comment: you should put a cut after both facts, or test that X > 2 in third rule

Comment: I tried both non-trace mode and x > 2 yet it still messes up at find_thing(2....)

Comment: How do you test it??

Comment: I put "find_thing(3, [1,2,3], X)." into SWI-Prolog's default setting without quotations. I also do the same thing with SICtus as my secondary compiler.

Comment: What is at_position/3 ??